# Windows task scheduler doesn't start task when the battery is low

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I create the task with `SCHTASKS.EXE /create /tn "TaskName" /ru system /xml ".\TaskName.xml"`
This is the content of `TaskName.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2023-01-09T16:19:18</Date>
    <Author>AuthorName</Author>
    <URI>\AppName</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2023-01-09T16:19:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Myapp\Myapp.exe"</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

As you can see `DisallowStartIfOnBatterie` and `StopIfGoingOnBatterie` are both set to `false`

But the task is not starting with lowpower until the laptop AC power is plugged.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/component-guidelines/battery-saver mentions that:

```
Windows task scheduler tasks trigger only if the task is:

Not set to Start the task only if the computer is idle... (task doesn't use IdleSettings)

Not set to run during automatic maintenance (task doesn't use MaintenanceSettings)

Is set to Run only when user is logged on (task LogonType is TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN or TASK_LOGON_GROUP)
```

How am I suppose to set the logon type in the .xml file?

Comment: What are you looking for?   Provide enough power (plug in the machine).

Comment: The task runs on laptop, and should run at logon as administrator, this doesn't happen if the laptop starts up and happens to be on low battery.

Comment: Low battery can cause apps to fail. Hence my suggestion to plug in (or keep a higher charge).

Comment: Well, there must be a workaround to start the task regardless. I can manually run the task on low battery and everything is just fine.

Comment: Low battery affects things in different ways.  Best workaround is to have higher level of charge.

Comment: @John if you don't have an answer, just don't answer, it's alright.

Comment: I did not answer - just comment. We all can comment.  I have been using laptops for decades. Charging them is the universal solution.

Comment: If the processor slows in low power, execution time may be exceeded. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/tasksettings-executiontimelimit

Comment: @DrMoishePippik doesn't seem related to my issue.